# How to Limit MinDate and MaxDate on TCalendarView component on Delphi 10.2?

Tags: date, delphi, calendar, components, vcl

I would like to limit a range date of `TCalendarView` component of the *"Windows 10"* palette of *Delphi 10.2 Tokyo*. The `MinYear` and `MaxYear` properties are not enough for me because I would like to limit a date range.
Is it possible to do this without overwriting ancestral methods? if not, which method might be the most appropriate to intercept the **selection and design** of the out of range dates?

Comment: Your version of Delphi includes the Konopka Signature VCL Controls (formally Raize Components), the components have a lot of extra features/properties over the standard controls.

Comment: @Brian, yes i know ans i have the Konopka installed, but visualy TCalendarView have a modern visual and i like it.

Comment: Not sure if this works, but you might link an event for OnDrawDayItem and just draw a blank rectangle for days outside your range.

Comment: I find it odd that Embarcadero would not expose this functionality given that the underlying WinRT [`CalendarView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview) control does have [`MinDate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.mindate) and [`MaxDate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.maxdate) properties, and the older `TDateTimePicker` had this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Delphi versions 10.3 and higher has the following properties:

```
CalendarView1.MinYear
CalendarView1.MinYear
```

Comment: Did you not read what asker said about "The `MinYear` and `MaxYear` properties ..."?